# What are the default transformation matrices set by ID3DXSprite::Begin?

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d

Unless the `D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE` flag is set, the `ID3DXSprite::Begin` method sets the world, view and projection transformations on the device.

These default transformations do not work well if sprites are rotated out of the X-Y plane so I would like to modify them, which will be a lot easier if I know what they are.

What transformations does `ID3DXSprite::Begin` set?

Comment: Note if you were use Direct3D 11 rather than the legacy Direct3D 9, you could use and see all the source for ``SpriteBatch`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID3DXSprite::Begin` sets the world and view transformations to the identity.

The projection transformation is set to `matProj`:

```
// pdev is the IDirect3DDevice9 pointer
D3DVIEWPORT9 viewport;
pdev->GetViewport(&viewport);

// Short variable names to make the matrix readable
int w = viewport.Width; int h = viewport.Height;
int vx = viewport.X; int vy = viewport.Y;

// The scaling factors
float sx = 1.0f / w;
float sy = 1.0f / h;

// The projection matrix
D3DMATRIX matProj = {
                    sx * 2.0f,                  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f,            -sy * 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f,                  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
       -sx * (w + 2 * vx + 1), sy * (h + 2 * vy + 1), 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```